# How to convert a Scala HTTP Route to a Java HTTP Route in Akka 2.4.7?

Tags: java, scala, akka-http

Seems to be nothing in the [2.4.7 docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.7/java/http/) about converting a [Scala Route](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.7/?_ga=1.26694324.887660477.1452004835#akka.http.scaladsl.server.package@Route=akka.http.scaladsl.server.RequestContext=>scala.concurrent.Future[akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteResult]) to a [Java Route](http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.4.7/akka/http/javadsl/server/Route.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like, currently, the only choice is to use [RouteAdapter](http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.4.7/akka/http/javadsl/server/directives/RouteAdapter.html), however please note that it's marked as an **INTERNAL API**.

```
import akka.http.javadsl.server.directives.RouteAdapter
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.{Route => ScalaRoute}
import akka.http.javadsl.server.{Route => JavaRoute}

object RouteConversions {
  def toJavaRoute(s:ScalaRoute):JavaRoute = RouteAdapter(s)
}
```